# Change opacity of single window

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, transparency, xfwm4

I notice Xubuntu can let me change the opacity of inactive windows, which seems nice for having small videos playing while showing my terminal below. But it quickly gets annoying when doing anything else – I don't want every inactive window transparent, and I'd rather not go into settings all the time to turn it off. Can I just set it for one window?

(Bonus points for turning it into a script that can both set transparancy, always-on-top, and remove window decorations)

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon two possible solutions. In the Whisker menu, type "xfconf" and open the Settings editor, scroll down to "xfwm" on the left and then in the main table either

- disable `zoom_desktop` – now you can alt+mousescroll on the titlebar of the window you want to be transparent

or

- enable `horiz_scroll_opacity` – now you can mousescroll-sideways on the titlebar of the window you want to be transparent (I prefer this, that way I can still do alt-scrolling for zooming, should I ever need that)

Comment: I had to click the programs menu (aka Start menu in Windows speak), then open `Settings Editor` then in there, from the left `Channel` column choose `xfwm4` and then I can see the `zoom_desktop` and `horiz_scroll_opacity` -- source (https://wiki.xfce.org/tips#control_per-window_transparency)

Comment: work with ubuntu 18.04, xfce 4.12. Oh I love this with my pomodoro clock. God blessssss